# UITableView.setEditing() not working to disable edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having trouble getting my UITableView to exit edit mode. Here is how I enter & exit edit mode, see links below for source -

**Enter Edit Mode**

*DbgTableViewHandler.swift(126):*

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        ...
        table.setEditing(true, animated: true);
        ...
    }
```

**Leave Edit Mode**

*DbgTableView.swift(105):*

```
    func removeCell(_ index : Int) {
        ...
        setEditing(false, animated: true);
        ...
    }
```

**Code**

- [Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hnp2ajl4i8uo9b/0_0%20-%20UITableView-Dbg.zip?dl=0)
- [ViewController.swift](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgz3nehshxnxos4/ViewController.swift?dl=0)
- [DbgTableView.swift](https://www.dropbox.com/s/joxmr7fspi3s2sw/DbgTableView.swift?dl=0)
- [DbgTableViewCell.swift](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tx9078i2z1znz8/DbgTableViewCell.swift?dl=0)
- [DbgTableViewHandler.swift](https://www.dropbox.com/s/von9go3qh4z4qwc/DbgTableViewHandler.swift?dl=0)

**Question**

- How can I get my table in the example to exit edit mode?

Comment: I posted many files up, hopefully this is useful. Let me know if anything else is needed for posting or for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are removing cell is wrong, you should remove it by using `deleteRows` way, not remove from the `dataSource` then reload table, replace it with this code below and it will work

```
func removeCell(_ index : Int) {
    beginUpdates()
    myDbgCells.remove(at: index);
    let i = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    deleteRows(at: [i], with: .automatic)
    endUpdates()

    //turn mode off (just cause, for demo's sake)
    setEditing(false, animated: true);

    print("DbgTableView.removeCell():       cell removed");

    return;
}
```

Also your project is over complicated for such a simple screen, remember more code = harder to debug

Comment: my goodness, this works. Tj3n, thank you!! I never would have thought my issue was with the cell removal, good catch wow!

Comment: talk about heading off to bed tonight with a smile on my face, thanks much!